# Removing extra spaces

Tags: notepad++, csv

I'm building a web site and I've got two CSV files. One is from *Loves Truck Stops*, a list of all their locations, and the other CSV is for my website to display those locations on a map.

I rearranged the *Loves* CSV to follow to formatting of my site’s CSV and have copied it over to my CSV. However, when I did, I got a lot of extra spacing between words.

There's still a lot of manual formatting I need to do in order to get them to look like the first 8 lines, BUT is there an easy way to delete all that extra spacing that's in between each word on each line? That way there's only one space between each word?

[image: My file]

There are over 400 locations JUST for Loves, and I still need to add Pilot, flying J, TA and Petro stops too. 
Doing it manually will just take way too much time.

For anyone concerned: I'm using the "My Maps Locations" plugin for Joomla;
I’m not sure if there's an easier way to convert the Loves XLSM to a CSV or KML formatted for that plugin.

Comment: Your problem is a lot bigger than just “removing extra spaces”.  You say you have two CSV files, but there aren’t any commas after line 8.  Please try to get a better understanding of what you want to do.

Comment: Yes I realize there aren't any commas. I'm manually adding them in, amongst adding other things in, which is why I stated "There's still a lot of manual formatting I need to do in order to get them to look like the first 8 lines,"

I also misspoke, the locations I downloaded from Loves website was an XLMS

Originally the Loves XLMS had everything out of order from what the "My Maps Location" plugin needs for the CSV. I was just copying and pasting, but I moved columns around to the right order and just C/P all and just now need to remove the extra white space between words on any given row

Comment: images are not very useful. Without the sample text it's hard for anyone else to test

Comment: You should share the two input files as text and not image

Comment: Why on earth, when you’re converting large files between formats, would you ask for an automated solution for “removing extra spaces” but then do the rest of the job manually?  (You do realize that you’re talking about converting files between formats, right?)  And what do you even mean by “I rearranged the ‘Loves’ CSV to follow to formatting of my site’s CSV …”? – just that you changed the order of the columns? … … … … … … … … … … And, please, if you’re changing the question, ***change the question*** (i.e., [edit] it) — don’t post comments saying “The above is wrong; I meant to say _______.”

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have said, your real problem is much bigger than extra spaces.  But if the spaces are all you care about for this question, then

- Find What = `\h+` (this will match any instance of one or more spaces, tabs, or other horizontal whitespace)
- Replace With = `\x20` (or you could use a single space, but that's hard to see in the post)
- Search Mode = Regular Expression

Trying to guess what you did: you went to https://www.loves.com/en/location-and-fuel-price-search/locationsearchresults or similar, then clicked the "Export Locations in Excel", which downloaded an `.xlsx`; then once the spreadsheet opened, you COPIED the data into Notepad++.  Explanation: When you copy/pasted from the spreadsheet program (I'm guessing Excel, but it could be a different one), that program included tabs to separate the various columns.

If that's the case, what you should have done: once it was in your spreadsheet program, do your various column-rearranging and column-deleting in the spreadsheet tool, so that it will match the right format for "your CSV".  Once done, then **File > Save As**, and pick **CSV (Comma Separated)** as your file-type.  It should then easily integrate with whatever CSV-reading system "your CSV" is intended for.

Comment: Simpler is just to replace two spaces by one, then keep clicking the "Replace All" button until he number of replacements is shown as zer0